# Undefined index Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Ao realizar uma `request` estou recebendo `undefined index`.

O código em questão:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'telefone' => $data['telefone'],
            'usuario_anjo' => $data['usuario_anjo'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

Minha classe:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'telefone', 'usuario_anjo'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 'password_confirmation'
    ];
}
```

Minha request:

```
email: "teste@hotmail.com.br"
​
name: "teste"
​
password: "teste"
​
telefone: "(16)98182-4833"
​
usuario_anjo: 0
```

o erro em questão:

> message: "Undefined index: usuario_anjo"

Minha coluna no `bd` está definida como `int`.
Alguém poderia me informar o porquê desse erro?

Comment: Antes de chamar a função create usa isso aqui: echo '<pre>'; print_r( $data ); die;
E posta aqui o retorno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ps: nessa resposta eu presumo que você esteja sobrescrevendo o `RegisterController`.

Seu código está correto só que o Laravel não está passando o `usuario_anjo` porque ele não está na validação, e as informações passadas para o método `create` dentro do `$data` são apenas informações validadas.

Dessa forma, adicione esse método na mesma classe onde está o seu método `create`:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'telefone' => 'required|string',
        'usuario_anjo' => 'required|integer'
    ]);
}
```

Isso irá sobrescrever a função `validator` original chamada ao validar a requisição e adicionará validação ao `usuario_anjo`, dessa forma, quando o Laravel chamar por `$request->validated()`, o `usuario_anjo` estará incluso.